# How to keep single HTML5 attributes under 80 characters?

Tags: html, formatting, src

I'm designing a web page and would like to keep all lines under 80 characters long, how is this accomplished with rather long URLs and still have them validate?

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?ref=http://www.facebook.com/cengagebrain&amp;width&amp;height=500&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:500px;"
  title="Facebook Like Box"></iframe>
```

The above code works, and validates fine, but as you can see the src attribute is much longer than 80 characters (especially after indentations).  Now if I throw in some carriage returns it still runs fine, but then it won't validate, saying I have a control character in my attribute.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a link shortner like www.bitly.com
Like this: http://on.fb.me/1cspwC5

But i'm not sure if this will work though.

Comment: Tried that, it kept the base URL, but not the PHP option tags.